# Задача по перебиранию массивов на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

При нажатии .b-2 выполняете функцию f2. Функция перебирает массив a2 c помощью цикла for. Выведите на страницу в .out-2 формате индекс+пробел+значение+пробел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const b2 = document.querySelector('.b-2')
const out2 = document.querySelector('.out-2')
const a2 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
function f2 (arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out2.innerHTML += `${i} ${arr[i]} <br>`
  }
}

b2.addEventListener('click', () => f2(a2))
```

```css
.out-2 {border: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<button class="b-2">Button</button>
<div class="out-2"></div>
```